# New Dataframe column as a generic function of other rows (spark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**How do I efficiently create a new column in a** `DataFrame` **that is a function of other rows in** `spark` **?**

This is a `spark` implementation of the problem I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174398/new-dataframe-column-as-a-generic-function-of-other-rows-pandas):

```
from nltk.metrics.distance import edit_distance as edit_dist
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

d = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'word': ['cat', 'hat', 'hag', 'hog', 'dog', 'elephant']
}

spark_df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d))
words_list = list(spark_df.select('word').collect())

get_n_similar = udf(
    lambda word: len(
        [
            w for w in words_list if (w['word'] != word) and 
            (edit_dist(w['word'], word) < 2)
        ]
    ),
    IntegerType()
)

spark_df.withColumn('n_similar', get_n_similar(col('word'))).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+---------+
|id |word    |n_similar|
+---+--------+---------+
|1  |cat     |1        |
|2  |hat     |2        |
|3  |hag     |2        |
|4  |hog     |2        |
|5  |dog     |1        |
|6  |elephant|0        |
+---+--------+---------+
```

The problem here is that I don't know a way to tell `spark` to compare the current row to the other rows in the `Dataframe` without first collecting the values into a `list`. Is there a way to apply a generic function of other rows without calling `collect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem here is that I don't know a way to tell spark to compare the current row to the other rows in the Dataframe without first collecting the values into a list.

UDF is not an option here (you cannot reference distributed `DataFrame` in `udf`) Direct translation of your logic is Cartesian product and aggregate:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import levenshtein, col

result = (spark_df.alias("l")
    .crossJoin(spark_df.alias("r"))
    .where(levenshtein("l.word", "r.word") < 2)
    .where(col("l.word") != col("r.word"))
    .groupBy("l.id", "l.word")
    .count())
```

but in practice you should try to do something more efficient: [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672/8371915)

Depending on the problem, you should try to find other approximations to avoid full Cartesian product.

If you want to keep data without matches you can skip one filter:

```
(spark_df.alias("l")
    .crossJoin(spark_df.alias("r"))
    .where(levenshtein("l.word", "r.word") < 2)
    .groupBy("l.id", "l.word")
    .count()
    .withColumn("count", col("count") - 1))
```

or (slower, but more generic), join back with reference:

```
(spark_df
    .select("id", "word")
    .distinct()
    .join(result, ["id", "word"], "left")
    .na.fill(0))
```